# Cannot access method in other project of java

Tags: java, jar, java-package

I have create one java project which has following class with it's body.

```
package tfimvalidation;

public class ValidateToken {
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Yor package imprort succesfully");
    }
}
```

This is java project now I have create jar file of this project and add it in other my dynamic web project.

There is I can access ValidateToken class and package with following statement

```
ValidateToken validateToken = new ValidateToken();
```

but I cannot access validateToken.display();

it's give this type of error;
Syntax error on token "display", Identifier expected after this token.

This is code of second project where I have use jar of first project.
    import tfimvalidation.ValidateToken;

```
public class Main
{
     ValidateToken validateToken=new ValidateToken();
    validateToken.display(); //Here gives above shown error.
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown the code *calling* display at all. Please provide a short but complete example.

Comment: Please add more of your code to your question, specially surrounding code for `validateToken.display();` call.

Comment: do validateToken.display();   v in lower case

Comment: Please be more careful when posting questions in the future. Make sure you include a full example, and make it an example of what's actually wrong - otherwise you waste people's time, as you have here by changing the call from `ValidateToken.display()` to `validateToken.display()` after two of us have already answered.

Comment: Sorry that's my mistake but above is my real code now and the method display() is not static so please give solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get compile time error  because , You  are calling `token.display();`  in the `class body`, and not inside a method or other `code block`. You can't do that. The least possible change would be:

Shift below statement :

```
    ValidateToken token = new ValidateToken();
   token.display();
```

Into a method like this ,

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        ValidateToken token = new ValidateToken();
       token.display();
    }
```

**Other Options**

**1) Init Block**

```
{
     ValidateToken token = new ValidateToken();
       token.display();
}
```

**2) Inside Constructor**

```
     Main(){
 ValidateToken token = new ValidateToken();
           token.display();

    }
```

**3) Static Block**

```
        static {
 ValidateToken token = new ValidateToken();
           token.display();
         }
```

When you put these statement other than your `main method` than either you need to create new Object so that `Init Block or Constructor will run` and if it is inside the `static block` , it will be called as soon as Class Loads into Memory , but I think you want to reuse the Object for further process also so I suggest you to keep these lines inside your `main Method`

Answer (score 3):

You can't just call a method in a class declaration like that. You can declare *fields* in a class declaration, but method calls (other than those used for field initializers) have to be in methods or constructors. For example:

```
import tfimvalidation.ValidateToken;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ValidateToken token = new ValidateToken();
       token.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not static method I have shown in above code

Comment: @user3526172: No, so you shouldn't call it as *if* it were a static method, using just the type name. That's my point. You have two problems in your code, and you need to understand them both.

Comment: @user3526172: Oh, and now I see you've changed the question so it *doesn't* call it like that. What's the point of providing code for us and then changing it?

Answer (score 0):

Call your void type method from main/any other method instead of calling as if declaring a field like:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {//main is the entry point
       ValidateToken validateToken=new ValidateToken();
       validateToken.display();
    }
}
```

Or

```
public class Main
{
    ValidateToken validateToken=new ValidateToken();
    public void myMethod() {
       validateToken.display();
    }
}
```

Or

```
public class Main
{
    ValidateToken validateToken;
    public Main() {
        validateToken=new ValidateToken();
        validateToken.display();
    }

}
```

if it were a method with say return type as int, you could have done something like

```
public class Main
{
    ValidateToken validateToken=new ValidateToken();
    int myint = validateToken.display();//then of course method name would been different
}
```

Comment: You need to call void method from another object in another method or constructor.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing

```
public class Main
{
     ValidateToken validateToken=new ValidateToken();
    ValidateToken.display(); //Here gives above shown error.
}
```

what you should do

```
 public class Main
    {
       //call this function from main
      public void function(){
         ValidateToken validateToken=new ValidateToken();
        validateToken.display(); // here v in lowercase
       }
    }
```

First you are calling display function inside class but not inside Main class function thats not allowed in java second
your method in jar is non-static so you have to call it after creating its object.

In case you want to call display(); with class name do
In you jar

```
public static void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Yor package imprort succesfully");
    }
```

In class where you called function of jar

```
ValidateToken.display();
```

Note: Also import the package.

Comment: The "what you should do" code still wouldn't compile.

Comment: @singhakash Because you are running method calls that are not within a method but rather in the class body itself. This will fail.

Comment: @JonSkeet and show-p1984 thanks for pointing my mistake .Updated my answer

Comment: He might have already imported the package else he will be getting the error  `error: cannot find symbol` 
`ValidateToken validateToken=new ValidateToken();`